# mysterious files and possible virus on ubuntu 12.04.2 server

Tags: server, security, clamav

IT services at my institution discovered our server sending out SPAM emails and flagged it as compromised. Further investigations suggest that it is indeed infected with a virus. For instance, there is a mysterious file: /bin/zcut which when run prints

```
W E L C O M E 
master
```

and opens a super user terminal. I have run sudo clamav on the /sys directory and observed clamav fail to open many files, encountering various errors and "permission denied"s. For example, the file

```
/sys/module/psmouse/uevent
```

seems to be restricted even to the admin account. I am fairly certain I am dealing with a virus here and I just wanted suggestions on proceeding. I would like to make as much known about the virus to the community before purging the system.

Comment: It is not a virus at all. look as as if zcut is a Trojaned SSH daemon. Your best option is likely to do a fresh install and use strong passwords, etc. How much do you know about forensics ? See http://blog.gogrid.com/2013/01/28/how-to-recover-from-a-linux-security-breach-forensics-analysis-building-teams-part-1/ etc ...

Comment: Why run clamav on /sys? It is a virtual file system that exports information about devices, there's no executable code in there. Clamav is useful to find Windows viruses. As bodhi.zazen said this is not a virus. Backup your data, perform a clean installation and set a strong password.

Comment: thanks a lot, I am no network admin so when it comes to this type of thing I am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the worst idea to have a look at the [Rootkit Hunter project](http://rkhunter.sourceforge.net/).

[rkhunter](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/rkhunter.8.html) can be installed from the repos.

Comment: At this time, rkhunter does not add much. We already know there is a Trojaned SSH daemon running ( /bin/zcut )that opens a root shell. The system has been compromised and now we are at the forensics stage.